# Setting a value if a Select input has a value of 0 - Contact Form 7

Tags: php, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to set a a select to have a value of 3 if the select has a value of 0.

This is what I've got so far.

```
<?php
// define the wpcf7_posted_data callback 
function action_wpcf7_posted_data( $array ) { 
    $jobYears = $array['job-years-1'];
    $jobMonths = $array['job-months-1'];


    if ( $jobYears === 0 && $jobMonths === 0) {

        $array['job-years-1'] = 3;

    } 

    return $array;

}; 

add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'action_wpcf7_posted_data', 10, 1 );

?>
```

HTML

```
<select name="job-years-1" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<select name="job-months-1" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
</select>
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

J

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: That's the thing, I'm getting no PHP errors whatsoever and the value is still 0.

Comment: Don't use strict comparison. Post values are strings not integers. Change your test to `if ( $jobYears == 0 && $jobMonths == 0) {`

Comment: @Dave That works perfectly! Thank You

Comment: I added it as an answer to your question in case others come across it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use strict comparison. Post values are strings not integers. Change your test to

```
if ( $jobYears == 0 && $jobMonths == 0) {
```